# app crashing on calling intent from another class to enable bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I'm new to Java and i'm trying to make a bluetooth connection. I've made a bluetooth class to enable and disable bluetooth, but when I'm calling the bluetooth class from another activity it crashes. I think it's the intent that causes the crash.

This is from my bluetooth class (Bluetooth.java)

```
public class Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {
private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

public void bt_Check(View v){
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "BT is ON, now what?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Bluetooth is currently disabled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("ENABLE BLUETOOTH", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Snackbar.make(v, "Enabling bluetooth", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(v, "Device does not support Bluetooth", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-04 11:45:17.104 23762-23762/com.hszuyd.noodle_.testing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.hszuyd.noodle_.testing, PID: 23762
                                                                        Theme: themes:{}
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3931)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
                                                                            at com.hszuyd.noodle_.testing.Bluetooth$1.onClick(Bluetooth.java:27)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$2.onClick(Snackbar.java:295)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".KickPanelActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kickpanel"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TribotActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tribot"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's the KickPanelActivity (The activity I was talking about) where I'm calling from:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kickpanel);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Replace this with something useful
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show(); //Action that should be run when the snackbar!? is pressed
        }
    });
}

public void button_bt_check_OnClick(View v) {
        bluetooth.bt_Check(v);
    }
```

Comment: your error log  please

Comment: Added the log(cat) :-)

Comment: show manifest for you activity, seems something wrong with theme

Comment: Is `Bluetooth.java` your class? Please post that.

Comment: It worked fine when the bluetooth wasn't in a separate class. (Added the androidmanifest btw).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to getDefaultAdapter in oncreate() so, try like this way hope this will work for you.

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_home, container, false);
    findViews(rootView);
    try {

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I can see one major problem here

The below line in your code

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
```

is wrong  it should be

```
 Intent yourIntentname = new Intent(yourActivityOrServiceSource.this, yourActivityOrServiceDestination.class);
```

Since your intent object is null, and you are trying to do some thing with that, and hence you are getting null pointer reference.

Found another problem from your comments

The intent is created inside another class, here an anonymous inner class OnClickListener. Thus this does not refer the instance of your Activity (or Context) as intended but the instance of your anonymous inner class OnClickListener.

So you can cache the this object like

Classname that = this;

and use variable that for intent

**UPDATE**

If your intention is to just enable Bluetooth

you can use

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

Comment: Hey, I've tried it like this: `Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(Bluetooth.this, KickPanelActivity.class);`
The Bluetooth.this is the bluetooth class, and the KickPanelActivity.class is the activity where I'm calling it from.

Comment: @Remco1250, can you post Bluetooth class here

Comment: @Remco1250, got it, it is not Bluetooth.this, it is just   new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class)

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara it doesn't build :(

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara 
`Error:(26, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<KickPanelActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)`

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara So where should I put this? (Sorry I'm a real noob)

Comment: @Remco1250 above the line fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara so i add: `KickPanelActivity that = this;` above the fab, and do `Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(kickPanelActivity.that, KickPanelActivity.class);`?

Comment: @Remco1250       Why kickPAnelActivity.that, just use that, it is enough

Comment: @Remco1250 check now

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Well that works too, but it skips the intent (I was trying to make the intent work).

Comment: @Remco1250, extremely sorry I cannot teach you Android here, this is not a platform to teach or tutor, you mentioned that you are a noob, so I shared an alternate solution.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara No problem, thanks for the help and information.